# Confused about XML serializer and mixed accessibility Properties

Tags: c#

I am using ApplicationSettingsBase to serialize some settings and I am getting confusing behavior I am hoping someone can explain.

So, ideally this is the code block I want, but does not work:

```
[DataMember]
public CustomClass TestProp { get; private set;}
```

If I use that code block nothing gets serialized at all, but no exceptions are generated.

So as a workaround I replaced that code block with the following:

```
[IgnoreDataMember]
public CustomClass TestProp { get { return _TestProp; } }
[DataMember]
private CustomClass _TestProp  { get; set; }
```

With that code block the class serialized with everything I would expect except the _TestProp property did not get serialized.

To make sure I wasn't crazy that this should work I added the following properties:

```
[DataMember]
public List<int> TestList1 { get; private set; }
[DataMember]
private List<int> TestList2 { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public CustomClass TestProp2 { get; set; }
```

and all 3 of those properties serialize as expected.

For now I am just leaving the property as fully public with a comment to treat it as read only but I'd like to know what causes this behavior. Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: are you using `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractXmlSerializer`?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply.

In the end, I think the answer is both. Based on the exceptions I was getting (specifically the exception about collections that implement IDictionary not being supported) I am fairly sure that ApplicationSettingsBase is using XMLSerializer under the hood.

This data structure is also being passed over a named pipe with WCF and I am fairly sure that uses DataContractXmlSerializer under the hood. However this oddity has only been confirmed with ApplicationSettingsBase.